# what are the major architecture changes in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am new to angular 2 and SO as well. I would like to know the major architecture changes in Angular2 compared to Angular. There used to be `$apply`, `$digest`, `$evalAsync` and so much more, why was so many changes made in Angular.

From what I understood, the performance was the major issue which has been achieved in Angular2. It's more lightweight and all.

Can someone please shed some light on this. A brief answer would be of great help, just for a jump start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice article in the docs of Angular 2 that may help you to get a good understanding of its building blocks: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

`$apply`, `$digest`, `$evalAsync` does not exist anymore since Angular 2 has no digest cycle anymore.
An Angular 2 application can be pictured as a directed graph of components.

If you come from AngularJS you also can make your components run with Angular 2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

There you can read really good explanation, how angular2 **change detector** works:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

And what in general are **zones**:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Here in brief about change detection:

[How does optimised data binding mechanism work in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584909/how-does-optimised-data-binding-mechanism-work-in-angular2)

This is really essential knowledge if you want to create fast apps.